# I can't understand this code structure. Can someboy explame how to execute this code?

Tags: c

In mediastreamer2, I saw a lot of this weird code that I don't understand.

```
static MSFilterMethod sender_methods[] = {

{MS_RTP_SEND_MUTE, sender_mute},

{MS_RTP_SEND_UNMUTE, sender_unmute},

{MS_RTP_SEND_SET_SESSION, sender_set_session},

{MS_RTP_SEND_SEND_DTMF, sender_send_dtmf},

{MS_RTP_SEND_SET_RELAY_SESSION_ID, sender_set_relay_session_id},

{MS_FILTER_GET_SAMPLE_RATE, sender_get_sr },

{MS_FILTER_GET_NCHANNELS, sender_get_ch },

{MS_RTP_SEND_SET_DTMF_DURATION, sender_set_dtmf_duration },

{MS_RTP_SEND_SEND_GENERIC_CN, sender_send_generic_cn },

{0, NULL}

};
```

and this

```
MSFilterDesc ms_rtp_send_desc = {

MS_RTP_SEND_ID,

"MSRtpSend",

N_("RTP output filter"),

MS_FILTER_OTHER,

NULL,

1,

0,

sender_init,

NULL,

sender_process,

NULL,

sender_uninit,

sender_methods,

MS_FILTER_IS_PUMP
};
```

or

```
MSFilterDesc ms_rtp_send_desc = {

.id = MS_RTP_SEND_ID,

.name = "MSRtpSend",

.text = N_("RTP output filter"),

.category = MS_FILTER_OTHER,

.ninputs = 1,

.noutputs = 0,

.init = sender_init,

.process = sender_process,

.uninit = sender_uninit,

.methods = sender_methods,

.flags=MS_FILTER_IS_PUMP

};
```

in sender_methods, those "sender_" are function in the same file. I don't know how other function to call then. because I don't see those function appear in other files.

The whole projet is in Github: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/mediastreamer2.

Thank you.

Comment: They are #defines in some .h file?  Anyway, github links are not useful to future SO users :(

Comment: ..manye they are called by looking up the #define in the struct and then calling the corresponding function?

Comment: Actually, this is #define in .h file.

Comment: #define MS_FILTER_DESC_EXPORT(desc)

Comment: MS_FILTER_DESC_EXPORT(ms_rtp_send_desc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example `.init = sender_init`: This will initialize the `init` structure member of the `MSFilterDesc` structure to a pointer to the `sender_init` function. The two things to know for this is [structure initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) and [pointers to functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions).

For the others, the first is a plain initialization of an array of structures. And the second is a plain and simple initialization of a structure.

Comment: Thank you, that means, when this structure initialize, all the function in structure will be called?

Comment: @Sven No, a function call would look like `sender_init()`. It's just gets a pointer to the function. Then you can use the structure members as functions. Again, please read about pointers to functions.